# Java-How do I Call a Method With A Return Type

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a return type method from another class but I keep getting the error that it is undefined for the type of the class. Here is the code I'm trying to call:

```
   public MyTask() {

    id =   plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin,this,plugin.getConfig().getInt("StunDuration") * 20);
    if(id == -1)
    {
        plugin.getLogger().warning("BLARG");
    }
   }
```

How would I call that method from another class?

```
 public class DamageListener implements Listener{
private antirelog plugin;       
public DamageListener (antirelog plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
}
    Player realplayer1;
    Player realplayer2;
    boolean playeradd = false;
    private MyTask task;
    public static boolean isDamaged = false;
    public static boolean timerTask = true;
    static Set<Player> Damagelist = Collections.newSetFromMap(new   WeakHashMap<Player,Boolean>());

 @EventHandler
 public void damage (EntityDamageEvent event) {
Entity victim = event.getEntity();
if (event instanceof EntityDamageByEntityEvent) {
    EntityDamageByEntityEvent edbeEvent = (EntityDamageByEntityEvent) event;
    if(edbeEvent.getDamager() instanceof Player && victim instanceof Player) {
        EntityDamageByEntityEvent edbeEvent1 = (EntityDamageByEntityEvent) event;
        Entity attacker = edbeEvent1.getDamager();
        Player player = (Player) victim;
        realplayer1 = player;
        Player player2 = (Player) attacker;
        realplayer2 = player2;
        if(Damagelist.contains(realplayer1) || Damagelist.contains(realplayer2)) {
            isDamaged = true;
            timerTask = false;
            System.out.println("Cancel");
            MyTask();
        } else {
        Damagelist.add(realplayer1);
        Damagelist.add(realplayer2);            
        isDamaged = true;
        Pause ps = new Pause(plugin);
        MyTask();
        }

            }

    }
```

Heres the MyTask class.

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable
{

private antirelog plugin;
private int id = -1;

/**
* Generic constructor
* @param Plugin task is associated with
* @return 
*/      
public MyTask (antirelog plugin) {
this.plugin = plugin;
}
public void MyTask() {

     id =   plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin,this,plugin.getConfig().getInt("StunDuration") * 20);
    if(id == -1)
    {
        plugin.getLogger().warning("BLARG");
    }
   }


/**
* Do stuff when scheduler tells task to run
*/
@Override
public void run()
{
    if (DamageListener.timerTask == true) {
    DamageListener dl = new DamageListener(plugin);
    dl.Then();
    } 
    else if (DamageListener.timerTask == false) {
        plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(id);
        DamageListener.timerTask = true;
    }
 }

 /**
 * Remove task from scheduler
 * @return True if successfully stopped. Else false.
 */
 public boolean stopTask()
  {
    if(id != -1)
    {
        plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(id);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Umm, perhaps you meant to write `public void myTask() {`?

Comment: More code, a stack trace.  Help us help you.  This is a poor question - not enough detail.

Comment: What is the error exactly and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What? You have to define a valid method first. Then call it on an instance of the class that defines it.

Comment: I can't add the void because the method has a constructor name and something gets returned in the end.

Comment: @RobertLu Constructors don't return a datatype value, they only return a reference to the instance they just constructed. Maybe your English is bad and you're getting your opposites mixed up. Also, can you provide the code for the entire class you are trying to instantiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `MyTask()` is a constructor, for the class `MyTask`, to be instantiated in another class, it must be prefixed with the `new` keyword, like so:

```
...
isDamaged = true;
Pause ps = new Pause(plugin);
task = new MyTask(plugin); //Note the `new` keyword
...
```

Also lets fix some other things too.

```
public MyTask (antirelog plugin)
{
    this.plugin = plugin;
    if (plugin != null) {
        id = plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin,this,plugin.getConfig().getInt("StunDuration") * 20);
        if (id == -1)
        {
            plugin.getLogger().warning("BLARG");
        }
    }
}

//public MyTask() //Remove the void, this is a constructor
//{
//  this(null); //Call the extended constructor
//}
```

Comment: When I try to do that, it says that MyTask(antirelog) is undefined for the type of the class that I'm calling it from. That's the problem I've been trying to solve. :\

Comment: The method doesn't take a parameter. Try just MyTask()

Comment: It says now: MyTask() is undefined for the type TestClass (my class that I'm calling it from).

Comment: Please post the entire code for TestClass, I promise nobody will steal it.

Comment: I renamed the class to DamageListener

Comment: MyTask is the name of the class I'm trying to call from the current DamageListener class. If you want, I can post the MyTask class as well.

Comment: Sorry if I'm getting things mixed up. I'm new to Java and I basically teach myself the basics so I might refer to the wrong terms sometimes. Oh Ok lol. But just saying.

Comment: He was talking to me @RobertLu ;)

Comment: When I change call the MyTask() method in the MyTask() class, it comes up with an error saying that MyTask() is undefined for the type MyClass. Otherwise, everything else works. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: My bad, fixed. To call a constructor within a constructor use `this()`

Comment: :D It works now! But I had to put this() before this.plugin = plugin; since a constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor. I don't know if it will affect anything though.

Comment: Yay, I realised that too and moved your code around, answer has been revised. Also, make sure you update your code in `DamageListener` to call `new MyTask(plugin);` Otherwise `MyTask` won't do anything.

Comment: Hmm, why is there a null inside this? As in this(null).

Comment: Because you have to pass something to the extended constructor, if anything you would be better off deleting the `MyTask()` constructor and leaving only the `MyTask(plugin)` one.

Comment: If I did that, would I still be able to call MyTask(plugin) from the DamageListener class?

Comment: :D Wow thanks you're amazing. Everything works now. I'm gonna test the code in a sec and post the results.